# LWC return string from APEX just shows [object Object]

Tags: lightning-web-components

I'm trying to understand returning info from APEX in the lwc and showing it in the html.  I'm calling the APEX, but the HTML continues to return "[object Object]"

Can you see anything wrong with my code?

.js...

```
import { LightningElement, api, wire } from 'lwc';
import acceptRtnSomthing from '@salesforce/apex/HelperAccount.acceptRtnSomthing';

export default class UltimateParentMRR extends LightningElement {
    @api recordId;
    somethingReturned = "Value in .js....";

    @wire(acceptRtnSomthing, {recId : '$recordId' })
        somethingReturned;

}
```

HTML...

```
<template>
    <lightning-card title="Ultimate Parent MRR" icon-name="standard:account">
        <div class="slds-m-around_medium">
            {somethingReturned}
        </div>
    </lightning-card>
</template>
```

APEX...

```
@AuraEnabled (cacheable=true)
public static string acceptRtnSomthing(string recId){
    return recId;
}
```

Again - output in the HTML is just ...
[object Object]

If I comment out the call to the APEX - the HTML output is
Value in .js....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All wire requests have two attributes upon returning: `data` and `error`. You're looking for the `data` attribute.

```
{somethingReturned.data}
```

Comment: Yep - that was it!  Thank you!